# Using @ViewChild to get nativeElement of multiple input with same template name

Tags: angular

How i can get the nativeElement values of multiple inputs with same template name using @viewChild.

I am using this way

```
@ViewChild('exLimit') exLimitRef;
<input type="text" #exLimit (blur)="getVal()">
<input type="text" #exLimit (blur)="getVal()">

getVal(){
 console.log(this.exLimitRef);//This will give only first input values
}
```

Is there any way to get each elements value on blur event

Comment: Did you try `ViewChildren` ?

Answer (score 3):

This code is working, it returns an array of `ngModel` with both elements signed with same template name

**TypeScript:**

```
@ViewChildren('childrenFlagInfo') childrenFlagInfo: QueryList<NgModel>;
```

**Template:**

```
<seg-checkbox #childrenFlagInformativaBox  
              [(ngModel)]="dto.privacy.flagDocumentiViaEmail">
</seg-checkbox>

<seg-checkbox #childrenFlagInformativaBox  
              [(ngModel)]="dto.privacy.flagPrivacy">
</seg-checkbox>
```

Off course you can return a templateRef or anything you want, just specify type in your viewChildren. In your `getVal()` you'll have to loop the `childrenFlagInfo` array to console log what you want.